# When was the concept of "art criticism" first seen?

Tags: cultural-history, art, employment

Today being an [art critic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_critic) is a full time occupation for some individuals. When/where does the concept of "art criticism" first come into being?

**Clarify**

I am **NOT** looking for a random person sharing a personal opinion. I am looking for a professional person or skill set, recognized by the public in general or an employer (such as the government) for their skill in rating/criticizing/censoring art.  They raised payment in financial support or public recognition. We recognize [Socrates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates) as a philosopher because he was recognized by his peers (*though I don't believe he was paid for the act*).

Comment: This question comes from a [new site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86147/art-history) there seems to be [some question](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20370) on if art history is adequately addressed & in scope here on History.SE

Comment: Victorian opposition to the middle class included the assertion that they lacked the "aesthetic sense" common to the upper class. The ancient Greeks had theatrical competitions.  In truth the first time anyone performed anything and one of the audience said, "Meh..." art criticism began.  I'm not sure this is a question that can be answered. Are you really looking for the first professional art critic (i.e. person who supported them-self by practicing art criticism)?

Comment: Ugh looked at Ergh's wall drawing of the antelope and said "meh" - true story ! :)

Comment: Socrates was paid for the act; he taught in the forum and students and their parents paid fees for his lectures. The Greek judges of the theatrical festivals are probably the first examples - they were paid by the government to judge the quality of the plays.

Comment: @CGCampbell yes, but everyone knows that Ugh was merely a mindless dilettante mouthing the puerile drivel of the ante-pre-nascent-modernists, and everyone knows how worthwhile their opinions are....

Comment: Socrates was supported by patrons, particularly among his students and their families. I believe that was the typical "monetization" method for philosophy in the ancient era. A less successful philosopher might have to fall back on family or personal resources (eg: inherited wealth) to make ends meet if patronage fell short. The same goes for pretty much any artist. So drawing a fine line for what is and isn't "professional" is going to be exceedingly difficult.

Comment: There was actually a decent market for philosophers' skills, especially the [Sophists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophist#Sophists_of_the_5th_century_BC)

Comment: Related question [Did Socrates earn money (get paid) for philosophy?](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/21343)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "art criticism", as well as the first attempt to formulate what it entails, seems to have been created by English painter [Jonathan Richardson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Richardson#Works) in 1719, in his essay *[on the Whole Art of Criticism as it Relates to Painting and an Argument in Behalf of the Science of a Connoisseur](http://books.google.com/books/about/Two_Discourses.html?id=v0sJAAAAQAAJ)*. This seems to coincide with the first large-scale public exhibitions of art in the mid 18th century.

Before that there presumably were folks who criticized art, perhaps even serially. But Mr. Richardson seems to have been the first to give this activity a name (or at least the one that stuck).

Comment: That is earlier than I would have anticipated; did he really suggest that such an individual would make his/her living from criticizing art?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - Haven't had a chance to read it myself. But based on all the talk about it I've seen, it looks like he's arguing for art criticism itself as an *art*, and laying out what that looks like. So an avocation rather than a vocation, if you will.

Answer (score 0):

[Winckelmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_history#Winckelmann_and_art_criticism), I believe, was the first celebrated **major contributor** to what we now know as art criticism.