# Did Socrates earn money (get paid) for philosophy?

Tags: ancient-greece, employment

I have only read Platos Apology, so I was rather surprised when [a recent comment said he "was paid"](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/21329/when-was-the-concept-of-art-criticism-first-seen#comment53410_21329).

A quick look at [Wikipedia find this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socrates)

> In The Clouds Aristophanes portrays Socrates as accepting payment for teaching and running a sophist school with Chaerephon, while in Plato's Apology and Symposium and in Xenophon's accounts, Socrates explicitly denies accepting payment for teaching. More specifically, in the Apology Socrates cites his poverty as proof he is not a teacher.

So it does seem there is some question.  Was Socrates paid for teaching philosophy?

Comment: This exact question has already been asked, downvoted, and removed because the answer is readily found in Wikipedia.